# How to call method of method at runtime?

Tags: java

I know using reflection we can call method at run time. I have one requirement `obj.getMethod1().getMethod2().getMethod3()` to be called at run time. Method Name will be know only during run time. Number of methods also differ during run time. sometimes it can be `obj.getMethod1().getMethod2()`.

Currently I am handling through array as below

```
 obj=initialObj;
 for(i=0;i<arrayValue.length;i++){
     tempobj=obj.getClass.getMethod(arrayValue[i])// arrayValue contains method name
     obj=tempobj;
 }
```

Is there any other better way of doing this?

Comment: Your sample code cannot work because you are not calling `invoke(obj)` on that method. Moreover `;` is missing on the third line.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your methods don't have parameters, you can do this:

```
public static Object callChainedMethods(Object obj, String[] methodNames) throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
    Class<?> type = obj.getClass();
    Object objectOnWhichToCallMethod = obj;
    for (String methodName : methodNames) {
        Method m = type.getMethod(methodName);
        objectOnWhichToCallMethod = m.invoke(objectOnWhichToCallMethod);
        type = objectOnWhichToCallMethod.getClass();
    }
    return objectOnWhichToCallMethod;
}
```

If you don't need to return the final return value:

```
public static void callChainedMethods(Object obj, String[] methodNames) throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
    Class<?> type = obj.getClass();
    Object objectOnWhichToCallMethod = obj;
    for (String methodName : methodNames) {
        Method m = type.getMethod(methodName);
        objectOnWhichToCallMethod = m.invoke(objectOnWhichToCallMethod);
        type = objectOnWhichToCallMethod.getClass();
    }
}
```

For example:

```
String[] methods = {"toString", "getClass", "getClass"};
System.out.println(callChainedMethods((Integer)10, methods));
// prints "class java.lang.Class"
// because it is calling ((Integer)10).toString().getClass().getClass()
```

Comment: My implementation is same as above. I do not want to iterate though methods that is my concern.  Iterating reduces the performance. So is there any other way of doing it .

Comment: @SoundariyaaJakanadhan Have you _actually_ experienced performance problems or are you just guessing? Even if there is a performance problem, reflection is likely to be the cause, not the looping. You've got an array of methods of unknown size, how else are you going to call all of them?

Answer (score 0):

This is util class, that contains common methods:

```
public final class ReflectionUtils {
    public static <T> T invokeMethod(Object obj, String name, Class<?>[] types, Object... values) throws Throwable {
        try {
            Method method = getMethod(obj.getClass(), name, types);
            method.setAccessible(true);
            return (T)method.invoke(obj, values);
        } catch(InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw e.getTargetException();
        }
    }

    private static Method getMethod(Class<?> cls, String name, Class<?>... types) throws NoSuchMethodException {
        Method method = null;

        while (method == null && cls != null) {
            try {
                method = cls.getDeclaredMethod(name, types);
            } catch(NoSuchMethodException ignored) {
                cls = cls.getSuperclass();
            }
        }

        if (method == null) {
            throw new NoSuchMethodException();
        }

        return method;
    }
}
```

This is how to call `obj.getMethod1().getMethod2().getMethod3()`:

```
public static Object invokeMethods(Object obj, String... methodNames) throws Throwable {
    for (String methodName : methodNames)
        obj = ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(obj, methodName, null);
    return obj;
}
```

And client code could look like this:

```
Object res = invokeMethods(obj, "getMethod1", "getMethod2", "getMethod2");
```